# Conditionals based on taxonomy

Tags: 6, nodes

editing node.tpl.php, I want to create a conditional statement based on the node's taxonomy which will not print the submitter info and de-links the title from the node.

How would I get the value of the node's taxonomy when it passes into node.tpl.php?

I've tried $sTaxonomy = $node->taxonomy and doing a strpos($sTaxonomy, 'static') and a in_array('static', $sTaxonomy) which neither returned true (or not false). I've tried attaching 1-3 terms on the content and trying both methods without luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In D6, $node->taxonomy is an array of term objects keyed by the term id, eg:

```
  [145] => stdClass Object
    (
        [tid] => 145
        [vid] => 5
        [name] => nineohfour
        [description] => 
        [weight] => 0
    )

  [147] => stdClass Object
    (
        [tid] => 147
        [vid] => 5
        [name] => anotherterm
        [description] => 
        [weight] => 0
    )
```

Just put a `drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($node->taxonomy,true) . '</pre>');` in your template to take a closer look.  You can then go through that array with a `foreach` (or `in_array`)to find if a term is set and then act upon that.  I would do this in a `_preprocess_node()` hook though and set a variable to act upon in your node template instead of putting all that php logic in it.